# Output from printing the contents of an int array by using a char*

Tags: c, pointer-arithmetic

Do you know why the output of the program below is

```
1000
2000
```

I am very grateful if you can help me!
Here is the program.

```c
int main()
{
    int t[] = { 1, 2 };
    char* p = (char*)t;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(t); i++)
    {
        printf("%d", *(p + i));

        if (i % sizeof(t[0]) == sizeof(t[0]) - 1) printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What output did you expect instead and why? Note: `t` stored 2 integer values and on your system that means it is 8 bytes large. `p` treats the integer array as an array of `char` and iterates over it. (BTW: That would better be `unsigned char *p`). You should run your program in a debugger and step through it.

Comment: You are not printing `1000 2000`,. you are printing `1 0 0 0 2 0 0 0` but without the spaces.

Comment: An `int` value evidently is here 4 bytes, little endian, hence chars{ 1, 0, 0, 0 } for int 1.

Answer (score 0):

It is printing the value of each byte in the value of `t` as a numerical value. The `if` statement at the end looks confusing, but just checks if it is at the final element then adds a line break before exiting. Here is the code rewritten in a more readable form.

```c
int main() {
    int t[] = { 1, 2 };

    // Get a pointer to he first byte in t
    char* p = (char*)t;

    // Go through each byte in t
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(t); i++) {
        // Print the numerical value of each byte
        printf("%d", p[i]);
    }

    // Add a line break when finished.
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The objective of this code is most likely to show if you are using [big or little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). From your output we can tell you are using little endian. If it was big endian it would have outputted `00010002`.

Answer (score 0):

You can clarify it a bit by changing the printf to `printf("%d ", p[i]);`.

What the code does is to iterate across an array of `int` byte by byte. A special rule in C allows us to inspect the raw data of pretty much any type, by using a pointer to character type and then access individual bytes.

`char` is however a very poor choice because of [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/is-char-signed-or-unsigned-by-default). Use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` instead.

As for why the raw byte presentation of an `int` with value `1` comes up as `1 0 0 0`, it's because your systems happens to be a 32 bit `int` little endian system. [What is CPU endianness?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640)

The `if (i % sizeof(t[0]) == sizeof(t[0]) - 1) printf("\n");` part is just to print the new line after 4 bytes.

A complete rewrite of the program might look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int t[] = { 1, 2 };
  const size_t t_items = sizeof(t)/sizeof(*t); // 8/4 = 2 items
  unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)t; // bug fix to make the code portable

  for (size_t i = 0; i<t_items; i++) // iterate across array items
  {
    for(size_t j=0; j<sizeof(int); j++) // iterate across the bytes of each int
    {
      printf("%d ", *p);
      p++;
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```